Magic trackpad moves the cursor, but does not click on a tap (linux mint)
So, thanks to Does the Apple Magic Trackpad 2 work on Linux?, I now have configurations that make my magic trackpad kinda work (quoted below)
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 1 1
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Synaptics Tap Action" 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Synaptics Click Action" 1, 3, 2
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" -157, -157
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1, 1
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Synaptics Edge Scrolling" 0 0 0
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Synaptics Finger" 0 0 0
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration" 2.0
xinput set-prop "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 18

Now the pointer moves around, and I can do a two finger scroll. I can click with the buttons, but I cannot tap to click. Maybe this is intended by the original configuration's creator? But I have been looking for a way to enable tap to click, and failing
(I have a magic trackpad 3, btw, if that is relevant)
